# API testing api.chucknorris.io

Tags: api, get

I'm new to programming, therefore i ask for advice.

There is test api https://api.chucknorris.io/. I need to send get request to https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category ={category} so that instead of {category}, there are queries from here: https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/categories , and the console gave out a joke from each category.

I decided to do this via few functions, but stopped after the first one.

```
import requests

url = "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/categories"

def list_of_categories():
    response = requests.request("GET", url)
    data = response.text
    print(data)

list_of_categories()
```

Ant this is output:
["animal","career","celebrity","dev","explicit","fashion","food","history","money","movie","music","political","religion","science","sport","travel"]

Process finished with exit code 0

If i understand correctly, i need to make a few functions.

1. Write a function that gets a link to a list of categories on the network and returns a list of categories in the form of a list of strings.
2. Write a function that takes the name of a category and returns a link to a list of jokes in that category on the web as a string.
3. Write a function that takes a link to a list of jokes in a category on the web and returns jokes from this category as a list of strings.
4. Call the first function, get a list of category names from it and in the loop feed each category name to the second function, getting a link to the list of jokes in this category, and then call the third function and pass it a link to the list of jokes in the category obtained from the second function, and save the jokes returned from the third function to the list of rows.

But im not sure about code syntax.